# Survival Analysis for time to recovery data

Tags: survival, random-forest, cox-model

I am working on a project where I have to understand the drivers of recovery time from an injury in a given sport. Thus, the objective is to understand the time to Return To Play (RTP) in days. The variables I have describe the injury (location, extension, age of the player etc.). A snippet of how the data looks like:

```
 RTP     Joint     Injury_extension         Surgery        Age
 56      Ankle          56%                    No           19
 41      Knee           100%                   No           27
 285     Elbow          100%                   Yes          41
 37      Ankle          16%                    No           25
 15      Hip            6%                     No           33
```

$RTP = \beta_{1}\text{Joint} + \beta_{2}\text{InjuryExtension} + \beta_{3}\text{Surgery} + \beta_{4}\text{Age} + \varepsilon_i$

I have been digging into the literature so as to select the most appropriate statistical approach but I am still unsure of how to proceed. My thought was using Survival Analysis (Cox proportional hazard model and Survival Random Forests mainly) but I am unsure because in this database everyone suffers the event (recovery), the only thing that changes is the time difference and the characteristics of the injury.

I have also thought of treating RTP as continuous (thus ignoring the right censorship of survival) and then using methods such as XGBoost or SVM to model the data, with the ultimate goal of obtaining accurate predictions and a good explanatory model by means of Shapley Values for instance.

I'd really appreciate if you could  give me some ideas on what the best approach to model this type of data is.

Comment: You mention "the right censorship of survival", but if everyone experiences the event, it seems you don't have censorship at all; you simply have time to event without censoring.

Comment: @alanocallaghan thanks for the comment. Yes, that's actually true. Then, what do you suggest it's a more reasonable approach (better), using Survival Analysis (with no censorship) or treating RTP as continous variable?

Comment: I guess it depends on the distribution of the outcome. A GLM or GAM could work, but I don't know which distributional assumptions make sense as a way to model the data generating process. You can still use survival models in the absence of censoring, so my first effort would be to try Cox regression and to examine the characteristics of the predictors and outcome (residuals etc). You could then compare other models to this as some sort of a baseline